# Disk Automatically Unmount

Tags: debian, systemd, lvm

For some reason I had to recreate a LVM partition. The usual procedure seemed to terminate successfully with `mount /my/new/mountpoint`.

But after checking the current status with `df -h`, `lsblk` and `lvs`, etc. I  recognized that my logical volume was not mounted at all.

Looking into the kernel log I found

```
dmesg
...
[1388925.704404] XFS (dm-7): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[1388925.715171] XFS (dm-7): Ending clean mount
...
```

So the device seemed to be unmounted immediately after it was mounted.

What happens here?

Answer (score 6):

The solution was

`systemctl daemon-reload`

The answer was found in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Jan  ... myserver kernel: [1388925.704404] XFS (dm-7): Mounting V5 Filesystem
Jan  ... myserver kernel: [1388925.715171] XFS (dm-7): Ending clean mount
Jan  ... my systemd[1]: my-mountpoint.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-myvolgroup-mylogicalvolume.device. Stopping, too.
```

So it seems that `systemd` had generated a unit file for the mount that conflicts with the new configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this helped